# SQL Server Group by Count of DateTime Per Hour and Update Max count into table?

Tags: sql-server, count, max, hour

I have this piece of code that counts the number of occurrences for a set of events on an hourly basis. Now I need the **MAX COUNT** and input that in a different table. I am new to SQL and I am having problems with the UPDATE statement coupled with MAX and all that is below. Can anyone help please? Thanks!

```
    SELECT CAST(locate_received_date as date) AS 'ForDate', 
    DATEPART(hh, locate_received_date) AS 'OnHour', 
    COUNT (*) AS 'Count'
    FROM BELL_DPRA2_locates_fact
    WHERE locate_received_date BETWEEN '2016-12-01 00:00:00.000' AND '2016-12-01 23:59:59.999'
    GROUP BY CAST(locate_received_date as date), DATEPART(hh, locate_received_date);
```

This script results is attached. [image]

Edit: This answer worked for me thanks to @agfc. I modified a bit to work for me.

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET MaxHourlyCount =
     (SELECT Max(A.HourCount)
      FROM (SELECT CAST(locate_received_date as date) AS 'ForDate', 
    DATEPART(hh, locate_received_date) AS 'OnHour', 
    COUNT (*) AS HourCount
    FROM BELL_DPRA2_locates_fact
   WHERE locate_received_date BETWEEN '2016-12-01 00:00:00.000' AND '2016-12-01 23:59:59.999'
    GROUP BY CAST(locate_received_date as date), DATEPART(hh, locate_received_date)) AS A)
```

Comment: Where is your update? Which table are you updating? With what values? Where is the code that isn't working?

Comment: Sorry I was editing the question as the table wasn't coming up properly. I attached a picture for the code output

Comment: This still doesn't answer. Please show the code that is not working or at least give more details on what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Now that I got a table that counts for events occurring on every hour from 0 to 23, I need to just add the max count, which in this case will be on hour 11 (just one number int), and input that in another table. Give me a moment. Let me update my question a bit. I'm confused at why the table I am updating needs to be posted

Comment: I think my answer does it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It seems like it should work but it is erroring out. I am still researching to see what I can find about it. Do you have any idea? The first select statement and the hour count is said to have caused errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
-- I'd rename your 'Count' Field to something else not to use the SQL function name.     
UPDATE myOtherTable
    SET MaxField = SELECT Max(HourCount) FROM (SELECT CAST(locate_received_date as date) AS 'ForDate', 
        DATEPART(hh, locate_received_date) AS 'OnHour', 
        COUNT (*) AS HourCount
        FROM BELL_DPRA2_locates_fact
        WHERE locate_received_date BETWEEN '2016-12-01 00:00:00.000' AND '2016-12-01 23:59:59.999'
        GROUP BY CAST(locate_received_date as date), DATEPART(hh, locate_received_date)) As MyMaxResult;
```

Comment: This seems logical. I am unable to execute this though. Keeps throwing me an error around the first SELECT statement saying Incorrect syntax...
I am checking all the names and everything

Comment: I am sorry, there was one little thing missing. I assume you're using SQL Server. At the end you need to give the name to your newly selected value. Check out the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `TOP 1` and `ORDER BY` to return the row with the Max HourCount. You need only join this as a subquery to your table to update or insert it as a new row. If you include the table you are moving this data to, I can update this answer to reflect your table.

```
SELECT TOP 1
    CAST(locate_received_date as date) AS 'ForDate', 
    DATEPART(hh, locate_received_date) AS 'OnHour', 
    COUNT (*) AS 'Count'
FROM BELL_DPRA2_locates_fact
WHERE
    locate_received_date BETWEEN '2016-12-01 00:00:00.000' AND '2016-12-01 23:59:59.999'
GROUP BY
    CAST(locate_received_date as date),
    DATEPART(hh, locate_received_date)
ORDER BY Count DESC;
```